# With SweetAlert2 how can I get the title and text on separate lines with a Toast alert?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

I would like to be able to use SweetAlert2 for my "growl" notifications on my website. I am using the Toast option and it works perfect. However, I would like to get the Title and Text each on their own lines and not inline.

**UPDATE:**
So I've inspected the element and it is using inline flex. Below is the output code of the alert:

```
<div class="swal2-container swal2-top-end swal2-fade swal2-shown" style="overflow-y: auto;">
    <div aria-labelledby="swal2-title" aria-describedby="swal2-content" class="swal2-popup swal2-toast swal2-show" tabindex="-1" role="alert" aria-live="polite" style="display: flex;">
        <div class="swal2-header">
            <ul class="swal2-progress-steps" style="display: none;"></ul>
            <div class="swal2-icon swal2-error" style="display: none;"><span class="swal2-x-mark"><span class="swal2-x-mark-line-left"></span><span class="swal2-x-mark-line-right"></span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="swal2-icon swal2-question" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div class="swal2-icon swal2-warning" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div class="swal2-icon swal2-info" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div class="swal2-icon swal2-success swal2-animate-success-icon" style="display: flex;">
                <div class="swal2-success-circular-line-left" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></div><span class="swal2-success-line-tip"></span> <span class="swal2-success-line-long"></span>
                <div class="swal2-success-ring"></div>
                <div class="swal2-success-fix" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></div>
                <div class="swal2-success-circular-line-right" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></div>
            </div><img class="swal2-image" style="display: none;">
            <h2 class="swal2-title" id="swal2-title" style="display: flex;">Welcome!</h2>
            <button type="button" class="swal2-close" aria-label="Close this dialog" style="display: none;">×</button>
        </div>
        <div class="swal2-content">
            <div id="swal2-content" style="display: block;">You are now logged in!</div>
            <input class="swal2-input" style="display: none;">
            <input type="file" class="swal2-file" style="display: none;">
            <div class="swal2-range" style="display: none;">
                <input type="range">
                <output></output>
            </div>
            <select class="swal2-select" style="display: none;"></select>
            <div class="swal2-radio" style="display: none;"></div>
            <label for="swal2-checkbox" class="swal2-checkbox" style="display: none;">
                <input type="checkbox"><span class="swal2-label"></span></label>
            <textarea class="swal2-textarea" style="display: none;"></textarea>
            <div class="swal2-validation-message" id="swal2-validation-message"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="swal2-actions" style="display: none;">
            <button type="button" class="swal2-confirm swal2-styled" aria-label="" style="display: none; border-left-color: rgb(48, 133, 214); border-right-color: rgb(48, 133, 214);">OK</button>
            <button type="button" class="swal2-cancel swal2-styled" aria-label="" style="display: none;">Cancel</button>
        </div>
        <div class="swal2-footer" style="display: none;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The header code is:

`<h2 class="swal2-title" id="swal2-title" style="display: flex;">Welcome!</h2>`

and the text code is:

```
        <div class="swal2-content">
            <div id="swal2-content" style="display: block;">You are now logged in!</div>
            <input class="swal2-input" style="display: none;">
            <input type="file" class="swal2-file" style="display: none;">
            <div class="swal2-range" style="display: none;">
                <input type="range">
                <output></output>
            </div>
            <select class="swal2-select" style="display: none;"></select>
            <div class="swal2-radio" style="display: none;"></div>
            <label for="swal2-checkbox" class="swal2-checkbox" style="display: none;">
                <input type="checkbox"><span class="swal2-label"></span></label>
            <textarea class="swal2-textarea" style="display: none;"></textarea>
            <div class="swal2-validation-message" id="swal2-validation-message"></div>
        </div>
```

With the main text part being:

`<div id="swal2-content" style="display: block;">You are now logged in!</div>`
Hope this helps.

This is what it outputs:

[image: This is what it outputs]

This is how I would like it to look:

[image: This is how I would like it to look]

**UPDATE 2:**

Thanks to the help from [alekstrust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1333916/alekstrust), I now have code that does what I need. Below is the full CSS I used:

```
.swal2-container .swal2-popup.swal2-toast {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: start;
    position: relative;
}

.swal2-container .swal2-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -20px !important;
}

.swal2-container .swal2-popup.swal2-toast .swal2-title,
.swal2-container .swal2-popup.swal2-toast .swal2-content {
    margin-left: 50px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These styles would do part of the job:

```
.swal2-container .swal2-popup.swal2-toast {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
}

.swal2-container .swal2-popup.swal2-toast .swal2-content {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Not the best icon alignment, though.

---

### Update

This will do a better job:

```
.swal2-container .swal2-popup.swal2-toast {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
  position: relative;
}

.swal2-container .swal2-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
}

.swal2-container .swal2-popup.swal2-toast .swal2-title,
.swal2-container .swal2-popup.swal2-toast .swal2-content {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

See https://codepen.io/alekstrust/pen/dybJXMo

Comment: I really like that this solution is CSS only. The one thing it is missing is is the vertically align the icon in the notification like int he image I showed above.

Comment: Updated the styles for more accurate results.

Comment: Thank you! So it wasn't 100% perfect as if there is more than one line in the message then the icon still isn't centered, but I messed with the CSS and change `top:13px` to be `top:50%` and then I did `margin-top: 20px !important` since 20px is half the height of the icon. Also I had to set `text-align: left`. I have add your code plus my added code the my original post. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `html` parameter to achieve the custom look:

```js
Swal.fire({
  type: 'success',
  html: `
    <div style="text-align: left; margin-left: 10px">
      <strong>Welcome!</strong><br>
      You are now logged in!
    </div>`,
  toast: true,
  showConfirmButton: false
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This CSS fixes the toasts, but doesn't affect the popups...

```
.swal2-container .swal2-toast { 
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 57px;
}

.swal2-container .swal2-toast .swal2-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
}

.swal2-container .swal2-toast .swal2-title,
.swal2-container .swal2-toast .swal2-content {
  margin-left: 50px;
  text-align: left;
}
```